# How to create an object out of array of strings in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, object

I'm new to `php`. I just want to create an object from array of strings.

I want these array of strings:

```
$arrEmails = [
   'johndoe@email.com',
   'foobar@email.com',
   'petersmith@email.com'
];
```

to be put in an object to be accessed like,
`$emails = $objEmails->email`

How is it possible?

Comment: just create an empty object, then declare the property, and why do you need such fashion anyway?

Comment: can you provide a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Just create your empty object and just simply add that property:

```
$objEmails = new stdClass; // initialize an empty object
$objEmails->email = $arrEmails; // declare the property
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a class like this:

```
class ObjEmails
{
    $emails = array();
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emails = array(
          'johndoe@email.com',
          'foobar@email.com',
          'petersmith@email.com'
        );
    }

}

$objEmails = new ObjEmails;
$emails = $objEmails->email;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I chose the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with -

```
$arrEmails = [
   'johndoe@email.com',
   'foobar@email.com',
   'petersmith@email.com'
];
$objEmails = (object) $arrEmail;
```